# How can I tell Jest/RTL to appropriately wait for a non-UI, async, operation to finish?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

**UPDATE**

After some digging, it appears that the spied upon method in my effects layer (`SheetEffects.clearAll`) is not actually being mocked which is why the `expect` fails and so this isn't an issue w/ RTL.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I don't think I'm thinking about this incorrectly, but please give a **thorough and well-thought** reply if you disagree.  KCD's `react-testing-library` [documentation](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library#wait) provides examples for asynchronously waiting for DOM to update before executing a Jest `expect`.  My issue has to do with what if there ***is not*** a UI update during a similarly asynchronous process (and this may be beyond the intended scope of RTL)?

Given:

```
  it('should dispatch the correct action when clicked', async () => {
    const { container } = renderWithReduxProvider(<ClearAllButton />, {}, true)

    // spying on this and checking if it's been called in the `wait` block fails
    // jest.spyOn(SheetEffects, 'clearAll')

    // this works within `wait`, but I don't need/want to test this here
    const spy = jest.spyOn(SheetApiV2, 'clearAll').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve())

    fireEvent.click(container.firstChild as HTMLElement)

    // this works, but I'm fairly certain it's a race condition
    // and I'm just getting lucky
    await wait(() => expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))
  })
```

Since I already have unit tests for the effects layer, I really just want to be able to specifically confirm that the component dispatched the correct action (via `mapDispatchToProps`).  There are other side-effect ways to see that this has been done but I want to *specifically* test that the component dispatched the correct action and not that a reducer was invoked as a result of this action, or that an effect was called.

**NB** The `renderWithReduxProvider` function creates a Redux store with our effects middleware, and returns a `<Provider/>` wrapped connected component.  Also note that effect functions are asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you do it is correct, just `wait` for the method to be called.

However, I don't think I agree with this statement

> Since I already have unit tests for the effects layer, I really just want to be able to specifically confirm that the component dispatched the correct action

In my opinion, you should test that the side effect happens. You see, calling `SheetEffects.clearAll` is an implementation detail. What if you decide to rewrite your app not to use Redux? Or what if you rename `clearAll` to `clearEverything`? In other words, what happens if you refactor the code? The test will break.

However, if you test the side effect, the test will still work because it does not care about the underlying implementation. The test will also give you much more confidence because you're going to test that the full feature works.

As a plus, you can get rid of the unit test for `clearAll` because you're implicitly testing it.

---

A little side note: when you use `jest.spyOn` you should reset your spy at the end of the test. You can do that with `spy.mockRestore()`

Comment: Agreed RE testing the effect function invocation.  As noted in my code block, spying on the effect function and checking that it was invoked fails while the call to the server succeeds leading me to believe it's a race condition.

Comment: Oh, also, we clear our mocks globally after each test in a Jest setup file via `afterEach(jest.clearAllMocks())`

Comment: It's a bit difficult to figure out the issue without knowing what your components are doing. Why would it be a race condition? What threads are running at the same time?

Comment: There's no threads.  I have a connected component, I click a button, it dispatches an action that's picked up by our effect middleware and it executes the effect function.  It all works except I can't spy on the effect function to ensure that it's being called.  My current guess is that the `expect` executes before the effect function is invoked due to how middleware executes.

Comment: But if you put the `expect` in a `wait` it gets called several times for a few seconds. Unless your side effect takes a very long time to fire this should not be the case

Comment: The issue is not RTL, but rather how the effects middleware registers and invokes the effect callback functions.  If my understanding of how spies work is correct, it replaces the actual function with the spy and delegates execution.  But the effect function registration happens long before the spy so when it invokes it, it's the real deal and not the spy.  I'll need to inject some logic into the middleware to test this accurately.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is not RTL, but rather how spies work (in general, I believe, but feel free to correct with a well-thought reply).  When a spy is created, it replaces the function being spied upon.  I believe the issue in this case is 1) that the effect functions are registered long before the spy is created and how the effects middleware registers and invokes the effect function.  By the time the latter occurs, it's not the spy that's invoked, but rather the original function.

I need to test out some different ways to inject logic into the effects middleware to allow for spying in tests.